# ExpandableListAdapter with CheckedTextView - complex selection logic

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have an ExpandableListAdapter that dynamically loads groups and child items for the groups. I would like to be able to create complex logic for checking the child items. Some child items will be multiple choice and some will be single choice. When you select a single choice item all the multiple choice items are unselected. I have no problem with the multiple choice items, but I am not able to unselect the items when a single choice item is checked. Any advice is welcome.

I do not include the source code, as it is pretty standard, but can provide it on request.

Comment: How are you unselecting the "multiple-items"? You might need to re-fetch the visible views so the change is visible.

Comment: I have not been able to unselect the multiple items. How do I refetch the visible views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark which items are multiple which are not, i'd create some boolean method inside the adapter. If needed with the help of array of booleans, holding the value for each multiple item inside.

And inside of your getChildView() you could simply do something like

```
if (multiples.get(groupView).get(childView))
    myView.setChecked(false);
```

To refresh the visible items you **might** need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Can't believe I spent so much time on this.

Comment: The only problem is that the checked boxes don't persist after screen rotation. How do I fix that?

Comment: Either create a separate array to hold the checked status of all checkboxes and make that array static. Or use onSaveInstanceState to save which checkboxes are saved and inside onCreate **if** the `savedInstanceState` is not null, get the states of checkboxes and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an `onCheckChangeListener`? If so, you could be experiencing a couple issues.

Firstly, if your multiple choice items are not becoming unchecked when you click them, it is because you are not explicitly calling `setChecked(false)` when `onCheckChanged` is called with `isChecked = false`.

If you want your multiple choice items to be un-selected when you select a single choice item, you must also expilictly call `mMultiChoiceItem.setChecked(false)` for all multi choice items in the `onCheckChanged` method of your single choice item listener.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to get a list of mMultipleChoiceItems so that I can call setChecked on them. I've tried doing it inside adapter and inside activity, but no luck. Ideal would be a function that would return mMultipleChoiceItem for a given group and child index.

Comment: You have to use resource IDs. Ideally all your list element views should contain the same id that points to a multi choice item. So to access that view, try something like `mListAdapter.getView(index, null, mListView).findViewById(R.id.multi_choice_item)`, which will return a reference to the multichoice item cast as a `View`.  You can iterate through your list adapter to get all of these views if necessary.